# Unstable Wifi connection on Ubuntu 14.04, stable on Windows 7

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

As in the title, my wifi connection is unstable with my Ubuntu 14.04 box; for 3 minutes it works, and then for 3 minutes it is down, and again it is up.
My network applet says that it is always connected to the network even when internet does not work.
On Windows 7 it works with no interruption.

What can I do to do some diagnostic of my system?

Additions

In my kern.log there are a lot of this repeated all over a lot of time

```
May 10 11:24:56 laptop kernel: [   16.068733] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May 10 11:24:56 laptop kernel: [   16.071742] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May 10 11:27:29 laptop kernel: [  169.045306] wlan0: authenticate with 0c:37:dc:a9:40:81
May 10 11:27:29 laptop kernel: [  169.062439] wlan0: send auth to 0c:37:dc:a9:40:81 (try 1/3)
May 10 11:27:29 laptop kernel: [  169.064467] wlan0: authenticated
May 10 11:27:29 laptop kernel: [  169.066174] wlan0: associate with 0c:37:dc:a9:40:81 (try 1/3)
May 10 11:27:29 laptop kernel: [  169.069739] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 0c:37:dc:a9:40:81 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
May 10 11:27:29 laptop kernel: [  169.069806] wlan0: associated
May 10 11:27:29 laptop kernel: [  169.069823] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Check */var/log/syslog* and */var/log/kern.log*

Answer (score 0):

Please make a terminal and type this in, it's good to know what kernel version and other information about your specific Ubuntu build.

uname -a

I know this may sound a little off but I have seen a problem like this before. If you're behind a router, set your Wireless network connection for IPv4 Automatic DHCP, set it so it needs IPv4 to complete the connection, then set the IPv6 for the time being to Ignore.

I have seen this in terms of some cable and xDSL companies assign a modem both an IPv4 and IPv6 address but it isn't brought inwards as of yet from the modem, so that everything on your network doesn't have an IPv6 IP address, despite having your router set as IPv6 bridge or pass through, it has no effect.

If this is the case, you will get IPv6 as "link local", meaning a loop-back virtual device is created for you in this case. It serves no purpose if this is what's happening. I tell people to turn IPv6 off by using "Ignore" in the Network Setting panel or via console / terminal.

If you're able to connect via IPv4 to your network and Internet after you have this selected, try doing an update. If it works, go to the Network Connection panel and enable IPv6 as DHCP Automatic but leave IPv4 enabled. If you connection slows down and you try to get an update again, which then slows to a crawl, cancel the update.
Then disable IPv6 again as "Ignore". I see this in a handful of cases every couple of months.

In Microsoft Windows, by default IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled and the IPv4 DHCP starts up first then IPv6 is brought up, very rarely have I seen an actual IPv6 connection through a residential gateway, meaning your computer is assigned an IPv6 address from your ISP directly, not just a link-local and loop-back device.

Comment: Linux mybox 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux